# Uso de Where en c# asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

que puedo hacer para que me guarde  lo que genera ese where cada vez entrada para despues mostrarlo en la vista, asi mismo como se guardando la del FirstOrDefault que cada vez que entra me lo guarda en ese add

```
        if (DedudccionesId != null)
        {
            IList<string> Deducciones = new List<string>();

                            for (int i = 0; i < DedudccionesId.Length; i++)
            {
                int idDeduccion = DedudccionesId[i];
                var Deduccion = db.Tbl_Deducciones.FirstOrDefault(t => t.DedId == idDeduccion);
                Deducciones.Add(Deduccion.DedDescripcion);
                if (Deduccion.DedTipo == "No Frecuente")
                {
                    var DeduccionesEmpleados = db.Con_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.Where(t => t.DedId == idDeduccion && t.AgeId == tbl_Agencia.AgeId && t.AreId == tbl_Area.AreId && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.DetDedEmpFecha) >= FechaDesde && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.DetDedEmpFecha) <= FechaHasta && t.HisLabEstadoEmpleado == true);
                    ViewBag.DeduccionesEmpleados = DeduccionesEmpleados.ToList();  // muestra las deducciones asignadas a los empleados


                }
                if (Deduccion.DedTipo == "Frecuente")
                {
                    // var DeducionesFijasEmpleado = db.Con_DeduccionesFijasEmpleado.Where(t => t.DedId == tbl_Deducciones.DedId && t.AgeId == tbl_Agencia.AgeId && t.AreId == tbl_Area.AreId && t.HisLabEstadoEmpleado == true);
                    var DeducionesFijasEmpleado = db.Con_DeduccionesFijasEmpleado.Where(t => t.AgeId == tbl_Agencia.AgeId && t.AreId == tbl_Area.AreId && t.HisLabEstadoEmpleado == true);

                    ViewBag.DeducionesFijasEmpleado = DeducionesFijasEmpleado.ToList();   // muestra las deducciones No frecuentes asignadas a los empleados
                }

            }


            ViewBag.Deducciones = Deducciones.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: porque haces un for del DedudccionesId? eso esta raro

Comment: ah porque en un dropdownlist  selecciono la deduccion

Comment: pero es una sola deduccion o es una lista? porque si es lista podrias usar un separador y aplicar el split() del string, luego usar el where con el Constains() para filtrar, de esta forma no necesitas ningun for

Comment: Si es una lista la que trae, porque la persona va seleccionar varias deducciones

Comment: porque poner el where dentro del for cuando no usas la variable DedudccionesId para aplicar en el filtro ?

Comment: Si la utilizo  for (int i = 0; i < DedudccionesId.Length; i++)
                {
                    int idDeduccion = DedudccionesId[i];    /// solo que cambia de deduccionesID a id deduccion , que es el que utilizo en el where , ejem.  var DeduccionesEmpleados = db.Con_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.Where(t => t.DedId == idDeduccion )

Comment: con ese idDeduccion lo uso para mostrar los empleados que tiene ese id de decuccion que entro

Comment: el tema que ese where solo me guarda los datos de la ultima deduccion que entra

Comment: Leandro Tuttini  como utilizo el split() y el constains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar el `split` y `contains` podrias recibir una lista separa por comas

```
string DedudccionesId = "1,2,3";
string[] items = DedudccionesId.Split(',');

var Deducciones = db.Tbl_Deducciones.FirstOrDefault(t => items.Contains(t.DedId));
```

asi de directo puedes obtener la lista sin necesidad de ningun `for` o `FirstOrDefault()` nada de eso, de la lista validas si esta contenido.

Nota: puse unos valores en `DedudccionesId` a modo de ejemplo

Todo el codigo podria quedar algo como esto

```
if (Deduccion.DedTipo == "No Frecuente")
{
    string[] items = DedudccionesId == null ? new string[] : DedudccionesId.Split(',');

    var DeduccionesEmpleados = db.Con_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado.Where(t => items.Contains(t.DedId)
                                                                                && t.AgeId == tbl_Agencia.AgeId && t.AreId == tbl_Area.AreId 
                                                                                && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.DetDedEmpFecha) >= FechaDesde 
                                                                                && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.DetDedEmpFecha) <= FechaHasta 
                                                                                && t.HisLabEstadoEmpleado == true);
    ViewBag.DeduccionesEmpleados = DeduccionesEmpleados.ToList();  


}
if (Deduccion.DedTipo == "Frecuente")
{
    var DeducionesFijasEmpleado = db.Con_DeduccionesFijasEmpleado.Where(t => t.AgeId == tbl_Agencia.AgeId 
                                                                            && t.AreId == tbl_Area.AreId 
                                                                            && t.HisLabEstadoEmpleado == true);

    ViewBag.DeducionesFijasEmpleado = DeducionesFijasEmpleado.ToList();  
}
```